# Why is converting between string and float wrong?

Tags: c#, string, floating-point

Please see my example below.

```
float maxFloat = float.MaxValue;
string s = maxFloat.ToString();
float result = float.Parse(s); // same with Convert.ToSingle(s);

bool mustEqual = (maxFloat == result);
// It returns FALSE, why?
```

Comment: Dmitry has the answer, but note that comparing floats for exact equality is almost always a mistake - you should pick the kind of precision you want, make sure it's within the capabilities of the given data type, and do the comparison only to the given precision.

Comment: @Luaan It is not a mistake if you're making sure that round-trips do not change the value, which is a valid thing to want from your serialization and deserialization. Even if later calculations are not exactly predictable because of rounding, there is no reason to accept rounding error on steps that can be exact (such as a float -> string -> float roundtrip).

Comment: Comparing floating-point values for equality is almost *always* a ***bug***.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You should use `"R"` format string:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#RFormatString

> "R" or "r" Round-trip Result: A string that can round-trip to an
>   identical number. Supported by: Single, Double, and BigInteger.
>   Precision specifier: Ignored.

```
  float maxFloat = float.MaxValue;
  string s = maxFloat.ToString("R"); // <- "R"
  float result = float.Parse(s);

  bool mustEqual = (maxFloat == result);
```

Comment: Hang on, doesn't that mean it *isn't* officially supported by float?

Comment: @deworde: `float` and `Single` are synonyms: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b1e65aza.aspx (as well as `double` and `Double`). "Type float ... .NET Framework type System.Single"

Answer (score 29):

> `// It returns FALSE, why?`

Because `float.ToString()` outputs a 7-digit precision number by default, so your `float.MaxValue` which has a value of `3.40282347E+38` (9-digit precision) will become rounded to `3.402823E+38` and your check fails because of course `3.402823E+38 != 3.40282347E+38`.

If you explicitly specify a format specifier to output `float.MaxValue` with 9-digit precision, e.g. `float.MaxValue.ToString("G9")`, your check will succeed.